# adding script for g502 mouse

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to make a two command script. I want it to where I push one button on the mouse and it does one command at a certain speed and then if I push another button on the mouse it does the same command just at a different speed.

This is the script I have:

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- to prevent it from being stuck on
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
        recoil = not recoil
        spot = not spot
    end
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
        if recoil then
            repeat
                --Sleep(35)
                Sleep(8)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 4)

            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

I would like for it to be this script plus say if button 8 is pushed move mouse relative (0,3)

Comment: Should mouse button #8 be pressed before left mouse button (to toggle the mode) or simultaneously with LMB (to change 0,4 to 0,3 only while it is being held down)?